# Trying to include a column widget inside a row widget but it keeps giving me error

Tags: flutter

```
Row(
children: const <Widget>[
        Text('Row 1'),
        Text('Row 2'),
        Column(
         children: const <Widget>[
          Text('Column1'),
          Text('Column2'),
      ],
    )

      ],
    ));
```

The code block is refusing to run because there are syntax errors. It only runs if I remove the entire Column widget

Comment: remove the const from code

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Row` or `Column`, constructor call here. And you can't use `const` here.  However, you can use `cosnt` on children, but if any of the children again  use constructor(Row/column/stack...) like this, the errors will show up.

```dart
  body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('Row 1'),
          const Text('Row 2'),
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: const <Widget>[
              Text('Column1'),
              Text('Column2'),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

As you can see, we are able to use `const` on `Column's` children.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it helps to you:

```
 Row(
      children: [
        Text('Row 1'),
        Text('Row 2'),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>
         [
            Text('Column1'),
            Text('Column2'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `const` on column or row Widget

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @TimeToCode said don't use the `cosnt` on column and row widget.

There are two possible ways to achieve output.

1. Using Row & Column

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text('Row 1'),
            Text('Row 2'),
            Column(
              children: [
                Text('Column1'),
                Text('Column2'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

2. Using Flex

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Flex(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            Text('Row 1'),
            Text('Row 2'),
            Flex(
              direction: Axis.vertical,
              children: [
                Text('Column 1'),
                Text('Column 2'),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```